# Como juntar vários commits de um mesmo arquivo?

Tags: git, github, commit

Fiz três commits no **mesmo** arquivo utilizando `git commit arquivo.ext -m "msg"`.

Percebi que esses três commits ficariam melhor juntos, como se fossem um só commit. Tem como fazer isso mesmo depois do `git push`?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nestas respostas https://stackoverflow.com/q/2563632/1518921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
git commit -m "GitCombinado com os ultimos 3"
```

Mais detalhes:
https://gist.github.com/patik/b8a9dc5cd356f9f6f980

Comment: Não precisaria do `git add myfile` antes do `commit`?

Comment: Não precisa, o `git reset --soft` já deixa preparado para commitar: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset